# Retrieving videos from the Videos app

Tags: ios

I would like to load a video from the Videos app. However, videos are stored in a different location than photos, correct? Is it possible to retrieve videos? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't possible through the MPMedia* classes, which I wasn't aware of. Here is how to select videos from the camera roll:

```
IImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.delegate = self;
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
imagePicker.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:imagePicker.sourceType];
imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
```

Unfortunately that only works for videos that have been recorded by you. It seems that anything else is unsupported.

Comment: MPMediaPickerController  is only for audio

Comment: I know this method. I am looking for the method that load videos in app 'videos'

Comment: And what I'm saying is that it is unsupported right now. Apple hasn't opened up an API for it.