# Getting the videos from iPhone in our app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

How can we get the video which are stored in the iphone library and Can we save that in our local database in our app and then we will delete the video from the iPhone Library, so that the video cannot be able to access in the iPhone library, but it can be used in the app.

Comment: you can access the video in your own app, but you can't deleted it. apple doesn't allow this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieving videos from the Videos app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975812/retrieving-videos-from-the-videos-app)

Answer (score 1):

NSString* mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
NSURL *url =  [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

NSString * documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString * fetchPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"TestDemo"];

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:fetchPath] == YES) {
    [fileManager removeItemAtPath:fetchPath error:nil];
}

NSError * error = nil;

if (Videourl == nil) {
    return;
}

[appDelegateIphone showLoadingViewforLandScapeRight];

[[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtURL:url
                                        toURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:fetchPath]
                                        error:&error];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`UIImagePickerController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) for retrieving images and videos from the iPhone Library.

You are not able to delete any image or videos from the iPhone library.

Comment: No you question is not worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `UIImagePickerController` class, and set the sourceType to be `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary` (this will present the user with the dialogue to choose an item from their iPhone library).

The delegate method `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` will then return a URL to the video the user has selected.

You cannot delete a video stored in the iPhone library. However, you could use the `UIImagePickerController` to prompt the user to record a video. You can then save this video to the file area of your app. By default it will not be saved to the iPhone library.

Check out the [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) for more info.

Hope that helps.